# Prove by induction that for $k\geq 1, F(k) = (13P(k-1)+5F(k-1))/2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

Prove by induction that for $k\geq 1, F(k) = (13P(k-1)+5F(k-1))/2$,
knowing that:

> $ F(0) = 2 $
>
> $ F(1) = 5$
>
> $ F(k) = 5F(k-1)-3F(k-2)$ if $k\geq 2$

and

> $ P(0) = 0 $
>
> $ P(1) = 1$
>
> $ P(k) = 5P(k-1)-3P(k-2)$ if $k\geq 2$

So far, I am able to prove that for $k = 1$ and $k = 2$, it's true:
$F(1) = (13P(0)+5F(0))/2 = (13*0 + 5*2)/2 = 5$

By induction:

$F(2) = (13P(1)+5F(1))/2 = (13*1 + 5*5)/2 = 19$

By definition:

$F(2) = 5F(1)-3F(0) = 5*5 - 3*2 = 19$

Now, I have to assume $F(k)$ and $F(k+1)$ and prove that: 
$F(k+2) = (13P(k+1)+5F(k+1))/2$

So far, so good I believe. But this is where the troubles start.

$$F(k+2) =$$ 
$$ 5F(k+1) - 3F(k) =$$
$$5((13P(k)+5F(k))/2) - 3((13P(k-1)+5F(k-1))/2) =$$
$$???$$
$$(13P(k+1)+5F(k+1))/2$$

After numerous attempts, I never came close to solve this problem. If anyone can help me out, that would be highly appreciated. Do I have a flaw in my logic? Thanks!

Edit: fixed typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  5((13P(k)+5F(k))/2) &- 3((13P(k-1)+5F(k-1))/2)  \\
    &= \frac{13}{2}(5P(k)-3P(k-1) + \frac{5}{2}(5F(k)-3F(k-1)) \\
    &= (13P(k+1) + 5F(k+1))/2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Define $$  A(k) = 2 F(k) - 13 P(k-1) - 5 F(k-1) $$

I wrote it all out,
$$  A(k+2) - 5 A(k+1) + 3 A(k) =  \color{magenta}{ 2 \left( F(k+2) - 5 F(k+1) + 3 F(k)  \right)} \color{blue}{-5  \left( F(k+1) - 5 F(k) + 3 F(k-1) \right)} \color{green}{- 13  \left( P(k+1) - 5 P(k) + 3 P(k-1)  \right)}  $$

By induction, $A$ is always zero.